# jQuery change event on select firing on page load

Tags: jquery, events, pageload

I'm having a strange problem in which a change handler on a two select elements are firing their change event when the page loads.

I've usually seen this when I'm accidentally firing the function, rather than referring to it.  However, in this instance that is not the case.

I'm using an older version of jQuery: 1.6.4

Here's (what I think is) the relevant code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var Entries = {

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        $('#entries-filter select').on('change', this.handleSelectChange);
    },      
    handleSelectChange: function(e) {
        console.log("changed");
    }
};

Entries.init();

window.Entries = Entries;

});
```

I can't understand why these events would fire on page load.  Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Please upgrade to the newest supported jQuery first. So many problems with older versions, especially before the 1.7s

Comment: Are you setting a value on the select when you are setting it? Maybe it's rendering the select, and then setting the value which would cause the onChange to fire I believe

Comment: Just checked this is absolutely fine script. No issues whatsoever, May be when page is getting loaded your select item is getting changed (_may be generation of options dynamically_)